# summary of the model is good but the plot is not normally distributed

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, data-visualization

I am doing a linear regression and the summary for the model is good however the plot is not normally distributed, i wanted to know if the model is still valid.

[image: the summary]

[image: the plot]

Comment: Could you elaborate on the sense that you find these diagnostics to be "good"?  They exhibit substantial departures from the ideal.  Whether that matters depends on why you are doing this analysis: some of the results might be reliable while others will not.

Comment: I'm new to this but based on the summary of the model, from what I understood is that the variables showed significance by looking at the t-statistics as well as the p-value. As well as R^2 and adjusted r-squared, in this case, I wanna check the significance between the variables. However looking at the plot from what i assume is that it is not normally distributed, i also looked at the histogram and it's not normally distributed. However looking at saphiro wilk test it is normally distributed. I am unsure if it can affect the significancy of the model or not

Comment: The SW test will definitely tell you the residuals are *not* Normally distributed.  The departures from Normality scarcely affect the p-values, though.

Comment: The tails of the residuals is heavier than normal ... and you have at least one point with a high leverage. You could look at leave-out some points and see if the results are stable, maybe bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

There is probably little we here can tell you beyond what has already been said, without seeing the actual data and model. I agree with whuber that with your rather large sample size, the non-normality will not have a big impact on the significance of your parameter estimates. If you are concerned, you could try a bootstrap or permutation test as a kind of sanity check. In the past, I usually found that these gave results very close to the standard parametric analysis, but as above, that very much depends on your data.

(See [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) for a motivation for short answers. Longer answers are always welcome.)